# porque sale el error failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Tengo el siguiente query en oracle

```
select NDATETIME,
Case NREADERIDN
    WHEN 52730 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA'
    WHEN 52731 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA'
    WHEN 52734 THEN 'TRIANGULAR'
    WHEN 52735 THEN 'TRIANGULAR'
    WHEN 52737 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA'
    WHEN 52738 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA'
    WHEN 52739 THEN 'JUAREZ'
    WHEN 52762 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA'
    WHEN 52768 THEN 'JUAREZ'
    WHEN 52769 THEN 'JUAREZ'
END AS NREADERIDN,
CASE WHEN NEVENTIDN IN(55, 43, 44) THEN 'EXITOSO'
     ELSE 'ERRONEO' 
END AS NEVENTIDN , TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') + (NDATETIME/24/60/60)  AS FEC_EVENTO
FROM REGISTRO_ACCESO 
WHERE NUSERID =? AND NDATETIME= ?
ORDER BY NDATETIME ASC;
```

y lo quiero pasar a JPA y lo tengo de la siguiente manera

```html
@NamedQuery(name = "findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1", query = "SELECT CASE myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn WHEN 52730 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN 52731 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN 52734 THEN 'TRIANGULAR' WHEN 52735 THEN 'TRIANGULAR' WHEN 52737 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA'
WHEN 52738 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN 52739 THEN 'JUAREZ' WHEN 52762 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN 52768 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN 52769 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' END AS myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn, CASE WHEN myRegistroAcceso.neventidn IN(55,44,43) THEN 'EXITOSO'
ELSE 'ERRONEO' END AS myRegistroAcceso.neventidn, TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') + (myRegistroAcceso.ndatetime/24/60/60) AS FEC_EVENTO FROM RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso WHERE myRegistroAcceso.nuserid =?1 ORDER BY myRegistroAcceso.ndatetime
ASC"),
```

pero me sale ese error y no me deja deployar

Comment: intente con @NamedNativeQuery

Answer (score 1):

El error se produce porque la anotación `@NamedQuery` se utiliza para definir una consulta estática utilizando el lenguaje de consultas de JPA, o séa, en JPQL ([documentación oficial de la anotación](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html)). Por tanto si necesitas definir una consulta en SQL nativo, debes utilizar la anotación `@NamedNativeQuery` ([documentación oficial de la anotación](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html)).